# how to access custom view button action in main VC

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, xib

I have created a custom view xib and give that view class. Now I take a view in main vc and give that class but now I want to access custom view button action method in my main vc. So how can I do that?

Here is my custom view

```
import UIKit

class TextCustomisationVC: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit(){
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TextCustomisationVC", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame =  self.bounds
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    }

    @IBAction func btnCloseCustomisation_Click(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    @IBAction func btnApplyCustomisation_Click(_ sender: Any) {
    }
}
```

[image: image here]

Now I create an outlet in my main VC and give that same class I can access those class outlets but now I want to access above button action method So how can I do that?

Comment: have you tried implementing those actions directly in the main VC? And then You can add the target action to the button in the main VC using `addTarget(_,action:,for:)`.

Comment: I can do that but I have to take outlet for this and create a custom action of that button, I want to access same created action in xib to main vc

Comment: Your problem is not clear. You want to get the actions in the main VC but you are also trying to access the action methods from your custom view. That's confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
let cusView = TextCustomisationVC(frame:///)
```

if btn sender is used inside function

```
cusView.btnCloseCustomisation_Click(cusView.closeBtn)
```

otherwise send any dummy button

```
cusView.btnCloseCustomisation_Click(UIButton())
```

**Edit:**

```
protocol CustomTeller {
    func closeClicked(UIButton)
}

class TextCustomisationVC: UIView {

    var delegate: CustomTeller?

    @IBAction func btnCloseCustomisation_Click(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.delegate?.closeClicked(sender:sender)
    }
}
```

// in mainVC

```
let cusView = TextCustomisationVC(frame:///)
cusView.delegate = self
```

and implement

```
func closeClicked(sender:UIButton) {

      // close button called 

}
```

Comment: ok I got  cusView.btnCloseCustomisation_Click in my main vc but what I have to pass as parameter?

Comment: ok now when I click on that button in Xib How can I get in my main vc? according to your answer I get this action early without click

Comment: you need to use delegate

Comment: can you post detail answer for that? you want to say I have to create protocol for that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use delegate here which you can implement in the main VC.

create a protocol like this:

```
protocol ButtonActionDelegate {
   func closeButtonPressed(_ sender:UIButton)
   func applyButtonPressed(_ sender:UIButton)
}
```

Then create instance of the delegate in your view like this:

```
var delegate:ButtonActionDelegate?
```

Implement this delegate in the main VC like this:

```
extension mainVC : ButtonActionDelegate {

    func closeButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
    func applyButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }

}
```

Then you can call the delegate methods respectively like this:

```
@IBAction func btnCloseCustomisation_Click(_ sender: Any) {
    self.delegate?.closeButtonPressed(sender)
}

@IBAction func btnApplyCustomisation_Click(_ sender: Any) {
    self.delegate?.applyButtonPressed(sender)
}
```

Comment: missed one step i.e. when we are initialise UIView in mainVC at that time need to set delegate.   customeView.delegate = self   Otherwise it won't work.